# How do I reduce the Counter EMF?

Tags: motor, dc, emf

I hope I can explain what I am asking.

We will connect a DC motor to a single phase rectifier. Motor will **carry a load**. And motor sould be able to spin right and left. And when it is changing its direction there will be a counter EMF that can burn the motor. 
The question is how do I prevent that ? Can I absorb counter EMF ? How?

Thank you :)

Comment: An universal motor?  Circuit?  Planned control circuit?   Looks like you plan to run a DC motor off of AC.   Back EMF may be the least of your problems.

Comment: How are you planning to reverse the motor?

Comment: I am planning to use L293D

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a small motor and you are thinking of using an [L293D](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf) you could use the chip to brake the motor before reversing it. If you disable the pair of half-bridges that is driving the motor it will free-wheel (coast). If you drive both inputs low (or high) and keep the outputs enabled it will dynamically brake the motor through the H-bridge. This will cause a similar surge to when it starts up. If you either measure RPM (with an encoder or whatever) or wait a sufficient time for the motor to slow to near stop then you can apply reverse voltage without getting the double current startup surge you would otherwise get from 'plugging' the motor. Since the bridge is absorbing the surge from stopping and immediately afterward a surge from starting you should evaluate the capabilities and make sure it will be okay.

You could also use the remaining drivers in that chip to switch a dynamic braking resistor across the motor (which is easier on the H-bridge and the motor), but directly shorting it will stop the motor faster.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, if you could eliminated the CEMF, then the motor would draw essentially short circuit current from your supply, and burn up, so that isn't what you want.  If you need to reverse a DC motor on the fly, you need to use a regenerative drive controller that can handle reducing the speed to zero and then accelerating in the other direction at a preset current limit.  Regen drives on DC motors are commonplace.  The other option is a variation on plug reversing... Use some relays (or contactors, depending on the size of the motor) to connect a resistor across the armature for a bit of time (dependent on your system) to dump the excess energy (also called Dynamic Braking), and then switch the contacts to apply the reverse polarity to change it's direction.
Also note, that many small DC motors can be safely plug reversed (just directly switching the applied voltage polarity), but that is harsh on both the supply and the brushes/commutator.  The windings would be fine.  What size (KW or HP) motor are you talking about?  Anything above fractional horsepower really should use a phase controller (drive) rather than just a rectifier, as the inrush current from starting at rated voltage will probably fry the rectifier and again, damage the brushes and commutator.

Comment: +1 Typical 4.9\$\Omega\$[resistor](http://www.powerohm.com/brakingLanding.aspx?partNumber=R2-40A01), suitable for a 40HP motor.

Comment: Generally, I size dynamic braking resistors to handle 150% of motor full load current at full voltage, so they depend on the motor size. That give sufficient breaking effect down to zero speed.  Note that for DB to work, the DC motor must have its field enabled, ie, if shunt, it has to be powered up.  A PM motor always has a field.

Comment: I am talking about a small 12V dc motor. I know that  when I change the polarity small motors can handle taht. But It is my homework. When I change the polariy CEMF and supply will be same direction and thats why I should prevent it. You explained well above. But my english is not so great. Do you have an example circuit ? 

 ps:I am thinking to use L293D (h bridge).